# Core Data not saving data in entity for the first time

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am developing an app using core data in ios. And there is lots of entities and a lots of data is to be saved so thats why I am saving the data in back thread using "private context" approach and using blocks. All is fine with all the entities, except for one.

In this entity the data is not saved first time when the application is launched and data is synced, but after that, if I sync the data again all the data in that entity is saved. Here is my code for saving the data:

```
let programAttendeeAssignArray:NSArray? = dict["data_assign"] as AnyObject? as? NSArray
for var paAssignIndex = 0; paAssignIndex < programAttendeeAssignArray?.count; paAssignIndex++ {
    let programAttendeeAssignObj:NSDictionary? = programAttendeeAssignArray?.objectAtIndex(paAssignIndex) as AnyObject? as? NSDictionary
    if let paAssignDict = programAttendeeAssignObj as? [String: AnyObject] {
        var keyString: String = ""
        if let eID = paAssignDict["id"]! as? Int {
            keyString = String(eID)
        }

        let paAssign: Conf_speakers = Utilities.sharedInstance.getOrCreateObjectOfEntityName("Conf_speakers", key: "id", identifier: keyString, localContext: privateContext) as! Conf_speakers

        if let eeid = paAssignDict["id"]! as? Int {
            paAssign.id = String(eeid)
        }

        if let attendee_id = paAssignDict["id1"]! as? Int {
            paAssign.attendee_id = String(attendee_id)
        }

        if let agenda_id = paAssignDict["id2"]! as? Int {
            paAssign.agenda_id = String(agenda_id)
        }

        if let updated_at = paAssignDict["id3"]! as? String {
            paAssign.updated_at = updated_at
        }                       
    }
}

let error: NSErrorPointer = nil
do {
    try privateContext.save()                    
} catch let error1 as NSError {
    error.memory = error1
} catch {
    fatalError()
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    appDelegate.managedObjectContext.performBlock { () -> Void in
        //var fds:Bool
        do {
            try
            print("Result MSG: \(appDelegate.managedObjectContext.save())")
            // fds = true
        } catch _ {
            //fds = false
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried without thread for this specific entity?

Comment: Yes without thread it is saving data in it.

Comment: Please share with thread code.

Comment: is `appDelegate.managedObjectContext` parent context or child context?

Comment: it is a parent context

Comment: There are different parts in your posted code that doesn't help us diagnose the issue: Can you please show us the `getOrCreateObjectOfEntityName`? How you are creating contexts and how you are calling the sync method, are you doing it within a performBlock? Btw, you have too many optionals not handled in your code. How do you make sure that passed data is not nil?

Comment: When you say the object is not saved, do you mean you try to access it in the **main context** somewhere else in your code and it seems not to be there?

Answer (score 0):

```
 let appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TableName")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        var results :NSArray

        try  results = context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        if results.count == 0
        {

        }
        else{

            let managedObject = results[0]
            managedObject.setValue(text, forKey: "TableEntity")
            //save data into table
            try context.save()


        }
    }
    catch{}
```